# CSS -- How to skin a select box with css

Tags: css

I've been trying to skin a select box with css to make a custom form. I've been able to successfully do with firefox but chrome and safari have some extra parts to it not allowing me to do it.

Comment: -1 What do you have so far? And what exactly do you wish as end result? Which parts exactly aren't allowed by Chrome/Safari, and how do they show them? Show us your style sheet! And especially for this kind of questions, some screen shots are more then welcome. Please improve your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set an `appearence: none` and you can do almost anything with it: https://jsfiddle.net/CUA9p/1475/

```css
body {
  background-color: #fef;
  margin: 2em;
}

select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
    background-color: #103;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 0, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 10px, transparent 10px, transparent 20px);
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #103, 0 3px 0 2px #649;
    color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 2px;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    text-transform: lowercase;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Hello</option>
    <option>World</option>
</select>
```

Also take a look at this: http://danielneumann.com/blog/how-to-style-dropdown-with-css-only/

Comment: You sir are a genius. #hattip

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great site that will keep all your form elements looking consistent. http://formalize.me/

Comment: I'm surprised no one voted this up, I thought this was great!

Answer (score -1):

i dnt think it is possible with css alone..cause select box is a control that is browser specific.. you will have to use javascript or jquery.

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/